# Не удаётся десериализация json при помощи Gson в универсальный тип

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня есть метод который отправляет запрос на WebSocket и получает ответ. Ответ в виде `json`, есть общая модель (`WsResponseBase`) для всех методов API и меняется только модель `Value` в зависимости от вызванного метода (`GetCompanyResponse`)

```
{
  "Class": "CompanyWsController",
  "Method": "GetCompany ",
  "Value": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Name",
    "LogoUrl": "LogoUrl",
    "Phone": "Phone",
    "City": "City",
    "Street": "Street"
  },
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "IsSuccess": true
}
```

Я пытаюсь его десериализация при помощи **[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)** и у меня это успешно получается, при помощи такого кода

```
fun <Treq, Tres : Any> send(controller: String, method: String, request: Treq): Tres? {
        val gson = Gson()

        // ...
        // код отправки запроса / получения ответа
        // ...
        
        val modelType = object : TypeToken<WsResponseBase<Tres?>?>() {}.type
        var response = gson.fromJson<WsResponseBase<Tres?>?>(responseJson, modelType)

        return response.valueData
    }
```

Но есть одно но, модель `valueData` типа `LinkedTreeMap`, а не того что я передавал в метод `GetCompanyResponse`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если передавать напрямую модель `GetCompanyResponse` вместо `TRes`, то всё успешно работает, но мне именно нужно универсальный тип, что бы при помощи одного метода отправлять и получать ответ с API

Модель `WsRequestBase`

```
class WsRequestBase<TValue> {
    @SerializedName("Controller")
    var controller: String
    @SerializedName("Method")
    var method: String
    @SerializedName("Value")
    var valueData: TValue
}
```

Модель `GetCompanyResponse`

```
class GetCompanyResponse {
    @SerializedName("Id")
    var id: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("Name")
    lateinit var name: String
    @SerializedName("LogoUrl")
    lateinit var logoUrl: String
    @SerializedName("Phone")
    lateinit var phone: String
    @SerializedName("City")
    lateinit var city: String
    @SerializedName("Street")
    lateinit var street: String
}
```

Так вызываю метод

```
wsClient.send<GetCompanyRequest, GetCompanyResponse>("CompanyWsController", "GetCompany", request)
```

Как можно решить данную проблему, уже несколько дней мучаюсь с ней и без результата

Comment: Покажите ваши модели, а то не очень понятно что вы делаете. Что такое `TRes`, как определяется или задаётся конкретный тип ответа?

Comment: Спасибо, дополнил вопрос

Comment: У вас `TypeToken`  параметризован шаблонным типом - получить реальный тип из шаблона невозможно. На каждый тип ответа/запроса нужно создавать свой `TypeToken` с конкретными параметрами на вызывающей стороне и передавать тип аргументом в функцию `send()`